# Javascript and SAML redirect fails

Tags: javascript, cors, saml, shibboleth

I try to access a resource at http://**/rest that is protected by Shibboleth SAML Serviceprovider. For that I make an XMLHttpRequest call to that address. On the resource server CORS headers are set and if there is no SAML Authentication everything works fine.
But if SAML Authentication is activated I get the following error in Chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load *****/rest. The request was redirected to 'https://idp.testshib.org/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?SAMLRequest=********', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

If I have a look at the network console I can see the following requests:

1.

```
Request URL:http://<resource_server>/rest
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
```

2.

```
Request URL:http://<resource_server>/rest
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Response-Header: Location:https://idp.testshib.org/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?SAMLRequest=*****
```

So it seems that redirect will be initialized but then stops because of the error above.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this working?

Regards

Philipp

Answer (score 1):

The 302 response is not an error. That is how a SAML protected resource requests authentication: by redirecting the user to the identity provider. Since you are making an AJAX call, however, the browser cannot follow the redirect to be authenticated.

**Assuming the common Web Browser SSO Profile:** The browser client needs to establish an authentication session in the same application that supports http://**/rest before you make the AJAX call. Most authentication session states are managed with cookies, so i would expect that once you have a session cookie for the application, the request to http://**/rest + the session cookie will result in a success.

There is also the  Enhanced Client or Proxy (ECP) Profile. This would require passing on the authentication SAML payload from the IDP to the resource - see the spec https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35389/sstc-saml-profiles-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf .